# How can I display a uploaded image with a modification

Tags: php, configurable-product, custom-options, ajax

I have a Magento T Shirt product that allows users to upload their own artwork. I want to use php to display the artwork overlayed over the top of the base image. Is there any way I can achieve this? 
How can I call the uploaded image and the base image?

For example, person uploads their artwork to product A. Underneath option loads the base image of that product along with the uploaded image laid on top of the product image.

Can this be achieved and if so, how can I call the base image?

Comment: I am not asking how to overlay the image. I am simply asking how can I call the base image and the uploaded image. I know how to overlay but just need to be able to call both the uploaded image and the product base image.

Comment: Did you found solution ?

Comment: Nope, just keep goind round in circles lol

Comment: any plan to purchase any extension ?

Comment: why you want to replace on base image, you can create some background image and you can place that image right like [here](http://www.dailyobjects.com/custom-cases/apple/iphone-se/custom-iphone-se-cases/slim)

Comment: Yeah after the same thing but I want to restrict movement. Just confused how to go about it.

Comment: than you created base image & overlapping uploaded image from frontend. can you please join here : http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42832/magento-discuss